# WSO2 DSS Cassandra Dependency

Tags: dependencies, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, cassandra-0.7

Is the integrated Cassandra server(version 0.7.x) loosely coupled with WSO2 DSS (version 2.6) or not? Will the usage of a newer version of Cassandra (e.g. 0.8.x) affect the DSS in the low level?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way we integrate Cassandra is by making it into a Carbon component and then integrating its authentication / authorization model to Carbon authn/authzn. There is no issue with having a new version of that component which has the new version of Cassandra.

If you're doing that please consider submitting a patch :-) .. we're planning to do it too but if you've done it already please share!

DSS has two functions now: storing data (relational storage service (RSS) and Cassandra storage service (CSS) for now .. HDFS next) and making data available via a service or RESTful interface. The latter is only available for relational data right now but the plan is to make it available for Cassandra data too using CQL. When using the data services/resource aspect of course the data does not have to be stored in RSS/CSS itself.

Comment: We do not have a plan to upgrade the Cassandra as a patch. Following the answers the upgrade is already included in your road map. It is safer to wait for your implementation :)

Answer (score 1):

Current CSS admin interface only works with Cassandra 0.7.x backend ( WSO2 CSS server ). Cassandra 0.8.x support will be available in future DSS and CSS releases.

Answer (score 0):

No, Cassandra feature will not affect any DSS functionality. It is actually planned to upgrade Cassandra to 0.8 in a future release and also having CQL support in DSS to query Cassandra data stores.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Currently we are trying to analyse the Cassandra for resource storage and trying to measure the risk of using an old version of Cassandra over a new one.